# Minimum Degree of Maximally Eigencentral Vertices

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

In [Grassi et al. (2007)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00222500701373251), they state the following theorem:

> Let $G(V,E)$ be a connected graph and $A$ its adjacency matrix, with spectral radius $\rho$ and principal eigenvector $x$. Let us consider the sets: $U=\{v\in V:x_v=\max_{i\in V}x_i\}$ and $W=\{w\in V:x_w=\min_{i\in V}x_i\}$ and let $d_{min}=\min\{d_v:v\in U\}$ and $d_{max}=\max\{d_w:w\in W\}$. Then $d_{max}\leq\rho\leq d_{min}$. One of the bounds holds as an equality if and only if $G$ is a regular graph; in this case both bounds actually hold as equalities.

So I interpreted the last statement to mean that if $d_{max}=\rho$, then $G$ must be a regular graph (or if $d_{min}=\rho$, then $G$ is a regular graph). But this statement is completely false; in fact Figure 2 in the paper, right before this theorem, gives a counterexample! (The counterexample is a binary tree of depth 3, and $d_{max}<\rho=d_{min}=2$) But I'm not sure what else it could mean. Any ideas on what they were trying to say?

Comment: You have your inequalities backwards.

Comment: I don't think so. It's saying that, out of the set of the most eigencentral vertices, the one with the lowest degree will still have a degree higher than $\rho$. Did you mean a different inequality?

Comment: I mean $d_\min \le \rho \le d_\min$.